# Refactoring a series of if statements

Tags: typescript

I recently started taking more of a coding role at my job and have been tasked with refactoring some rough code.

```
if (item.market === true) properties.marketPlace = true
if (!itemHasEssentialFields(item)) properties.lackingData = true
if (!item.availableOnline) properties.pickupOnly = true
if (item.bundle) properties.bundle = true
if (item.freight) properties.freightOnly = true
```

it goes on like this for another 15 lines of if statements setting different keys of properties to true. Whats the best way to go about refactoring this?

Comment: If a statement is not fulfilled, can the property value be `false`? Eg could `properties.marketPlace` be `false` if `market` isn't true?

Comment: No, the code that relies on it expects the object fields to not be populated, I can refactor that code as well (and probably should)

Answer (score 1):

If the values can be just booleans, then this can be done moderately more concisely with `Object.assign`:

```
Object.assign(properties, {
  marketPlace: item.market,
  lackingData: !itemHasEssentialFields(item),
  pickupOnly: !item.availableOnline,
  bundle: item.bundle, // may need to cast this to Boolean
  freightOnly: item.freight, // may need to cast this to Boolean
  // etc
```

If the `properties` starts out empty, declaring the object outright with just an initializer would be even better:

```
const properties = {
  marketPlace: item.market,
  lackingData: !itemHasEssentialFields(item),
  pickupOnly: !item.availableOnline,
  bundle: item.bundle,
  freightOnly: item.freight,
  // ...
```

If the values *must* be either `true` or nonexistent, you could turn the above object into one with only the truthy properties by filtering the entires:

```
const propertiesWithHoles = Object.fromEntries(
  Object.entries(properties)
    .filter(entry => entry[1])
);
```

But that's a strange data structure. Having booleans instead would make more sense, if at all possible.

Comment: I like your solutions but I was also thinking about creating some types and setting these things dynamically according to a set of rules and mappings, what do you think?

Comment: It's an option, but I don't think any approach will be as clean and simple as a plain object literal.